# How to update vue2-frappe chart?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've been breaking my head over this for the last few hours and no matter where I look I can't seem to find the answer.

I'm using [vue2-frappe](https://github.com/JustSteveKing/vue2-frappe) as my chart library. I'm using a simple bar chart to display certain values by day. Everything was fine until my higher-ups decided they wanted to show a whole year's worth of values on this chart, meaning I have to add some pagination to it.

The problem is, now I can't figure out *how* to make the chart rerender. I've tried replacing the entire object I've bound the chart to, as well as manipulating specific values, but nothing seems to make the component rerender.

In the documentation for frappe.js, you can modify data via [specific methods](https://frappe.io/charts/docs/update_state/modify_data), but this being Vue I can't just call chart.update() like in normal .js. And if I inspect the component via vue dev tools, I can see it contains the modified data, it just doesn't redraw itself.

Anyone have an idea what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to force update the view component.

VueJs reactivity can sometimes be confusing where you think it should react to changes but it doesn't.

You can force a view update like so:

```
// Globally
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.forceUpdate();

// Using the component instance
export default {
    methods: {
        methodThatForcesUpdate() {
        // ...
        this.$forceUpdate();  // Notice we have to use a $ here
        // ...
    }
  }
}
```

You can read about correct ways of re-rendering here: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render

There are caveats to this approach as outlined in vueJs's docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

**Note #**

A force re-render wont update computed values, but your computed property shouldn't contain any external non-reactive variable anyway.

**Note 2**
The above article written by Michael Thiessen also states the best way in his opinion is key-changing which I think we all should be aware of.

I hope this puts you on the right track. It sounds like (with limited information) you could be replacing the data but using the same key.

Comment: YES, thank you! Key-changing is enough. I've tried forceUpdate() before, having read the same article you've linked here, but for some reason forgot about the keys.

Comment: Happy to help :)